# Web scraping PDF

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

Can someone let me know how to download the pdf here which is hidden and only a save popup comes when we click the button from this website https://indiankanoon.org/doc/27901/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Read [ask], first, and they try *something* on your own and share it as a [mre].